# iOS Cocoa Frameworks multiple dependencies in workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, dependencies, ios-frameworks

I have a workspace with a following hierarchy

```
* App Project (uses Framework A & Framework B)
* 'Cocoa Framework A' Project
     - contains 'sub-framework B'
```

Both 'App Project' and 'Framework A' uses sub-framework B.
When I add sub-frameworks B to 'Framework A' linked frameworks, it compiles fine but I get linker errors when 'App Project' is compiled (it can't find sub-framework B symbols).

However, when I add 'sub-framework B' to linked frameworks in 'App Project', everything compiles fine, but when the app finish launching, I see warnings in console:

> objc[53023]: Class AWSS3PutBucketLifecycleConfigurationRequest is
>   implemented in both
>   [path-to-Derived-Data]/FrameworkA.framework/FrameworkA and
>   [path-to-simulator-bundle]/App.app/Aoo.
>
> One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I'm losing my mind as I can't find any solution to this.
Obviously, I need ''sub-framework B'' to be linked only once at the end of compiling.
Can you give me some tips how to solve this issue?

I'm attaching sample project with described problem:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24532134/Example.zip

Just compile it and see warnings in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Warning you get is not of a big ones - as long as you sure, that both FrameworkA and application uses same version of subframework, it won't be a problem. However, as a good developer, you should worry about such warnings.

What I can propose to you - remove FrameworkB dependency from application and include its umbrella header into umbrella header of FrameworkA. In that way, whenever you link FrameworkA, you automatically link FrameworkB and you have access to it's functionality declaration by including FrameworkA umbrella header

Here is your example set the way I described

[Example project](http://www.ex.ua/321665426183)

Comment: Thanks Sergii for the response. Your example project works as expected but it has one major issue. Let's say "FrameworkB" has ClassA and ClassB.   "FrameworkA" uses "ClassA" and "App" uses "ClassB". In such case, I get linker errors because "ClassB" was not linked with FrameworkA because it has never been used there. Apparently, importing headers won't link all the symbols.

Comment: I've added "-all_load" linker flag to FrameworkA and now it works. But I have doubts if that's a right approach. It's gonna increase build size significantly, isn't it?

Comment: The thing is, if you don't include ClassB into FrameworkB umbrella header - it means, it is private for FrameworkB usage only. If you include it in umbrella header - you include it in all places, whether you need it or not. It is like with UIKit - you always write <UIKit/UIKit.h>, even if you only need UIColor from it. For second question - yes, -all_load will increase size. Significantly or not - it depends

Comment: I do import ClassB in FrameworkB umbrella header. However, ClassB is not linked as it's never used in any "*.m" file of FrameworkB :< It would be great if missing symbols could be also linked when compiling the App... Argh, it sucks. Anyway, I can't think of other solution than "-all_load" flag.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Well, yeah, you'll need to build your FrameworkA with -ObjC linker flag.

Comment: I've make some search and came up with conclusion, that main advice here is to 1. Link FrameworkB separately to App and to FrameworkA with different class names or, if it cannot be done 2. Don't be bothered by this log message, just be sure that both implementations mentioned in are coming from the same FrameworkB. I guess, in your case, advice 2 would fully suffice, since it is exactly the same FmB for FmA and App.

Comment: The only real reason not to use approach 2. is if you need to use different version of same FrameworkB in FrameworkA and your Application - that will cause you problems

Comment: Yup, I cannot change framework names so the only solution I see is either that linking with -all_load flag or ignoring messages. I'm really confused. I wish some Apple expert could tell us whether it's the only way.

Comment: Hi @SergiiMartynenkoJr, Im also trying to do the similar approach but not so successful. I cannot access your project anymore.
When i try to Import FrameworkA into the App. it says 'Cannot find the frameworkB' or 'No such module FrameworkB' 
The same problem as msmialko mentioned. How did you solve this problem ? How can i tell my App to find FrameworkB (Which is a sub framework of frameworkA )

Comment: @msmialko, did you came to a conclusion, what to do for this problem?